# I fail to retrieve data from mysql in my android application

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am new to android application development. I am developing an application that will retrieve news from mysql database. I first wrote PHP script that extract news title and content from database and ouputs the JSON encoded data successfully, then in my application i wrote the following codes that will take JSON encoded data and display it to my application. I tried to catch some errors as well and i realized that i get the error while taking the data and try to display them. please have look on my codes and try to help me debugging it as i don't get where exactly am i doing mistake.

```
package com.jetas.vpl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

`import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;


import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.StrictMode;

import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_single_post);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    getData();
}

public void getData() {
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
    //TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    //textview.setText("Why are you stubborn");
    InputStream isr = null;
    String result = "";
    String url = "http://192.168.1.1/vpl/getnews.php";
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        isr = httpEntity.getContent();
        //textview2.setText("Test Passed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in HTTP Connection" + e.toString());
        textview.setText("Connection Failed");
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");
            //textview2.setText("Test Passed");
        }

        isr.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        //textview2.setText("Test Passed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        textview.setText("Buffer reader problem");
    }

    try {

        //String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(1);

            String newsTitle = json.getString("newsTitle");
            textview.setText(newsTitle);
            /*s = s + "Title: " + json.getString("newsTitle") + "\n"
                    + "Content: " + json.getString("newsContent") + "\n\n";
            textview.setText(s); */
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data" + e.toString());
        textview.setText("Error in Parsing Data !!!!!");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Which line does it occur on?

Answer (score 0):

if it is localhost that you are accessing from emulator, try `"http://10.0.2.2/vpl/getnews.php"`.

Also, perform the network operation inside a separate thread, preferably using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Here is a good [toutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask)